# Issue with Expressions when debugging JSP pages

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I'm using eclipse 3.6.1 and WTP 3.2.3 on centOS 5.5.

I have this issue where my expression values are showing up as blank when stepping through a jsp page (see screenshot)[image: screenshot]. The same objects appear fine in the variables pane. I tried to see if I there was setting that might be impacting this behavior but didn't see anything. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug ticket for this issue:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335633

Comment: eh, it is not fixed yet